# ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host + HP Procurve

Tags: debian, ssh, ssh-tunneling

im trying to connect to our HP Procurve switch via ssh from a linux machine and im getting the error: "ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host." (also as root)

I can connect to other Linux machines via ssh without any trouble.
Connectin to the Switch via Windows + Putty also works.

Its a standard Debian install without any speficic configuration.

Did i forget something?

```
    -vv 1.0.0.20
OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u3, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "1.0.0.20" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 1.0.0.20 [1.0.0.20] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u3
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Comment: crypto that is not used by default anymore. At work, or I would find you the duplicate of this question.

Comment: I saw many posts with this problem but they seemed to have different troubles. That could be it since the firmware is pretty old (2011) but i cant manage to find anything newer for it. i added the debug log for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

When an SSH client makes a TCP connection to a server, the first data exchange to take place is for the server to send its version string to the client. The message that you're getting indicates that the server didn't send its version string to the client and closed the TCP connection instead.

This isn't an authentication failure. The server hasn't sent its host key to the client yet, and the client hasn't tried to authenticate to the server yet. The server just accepted the TCP connection from the client and then dropped it.

The simplest explanation for this behavior is that the server is configured not to accept connections only from certain IP addresses, and you're trying to connect from a system which isn't permitted to connect to the server.

Comment: My bad u are totally right. Someone had an IP restriction on the ssh connection on the Switch. Why i didnt realized it we have it only on ALL HP Curve and not on the others which are newer. Thanks problem solved